# Can I filter Event Viewer for a determined Exception message?

Tags: windows-server-2003

O/S: Windows Server 2003. IIS 6.0. There is no SQL-Server.

I'm looking for filtering all events that have this Exception message: "Connection request timed out". Would it be possible?
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Heres my powershell one-liner.
This will output a table with the the Date and Time of each occurrence on the error.

```
get-eventlog -LogName Application | Select TimeGenerated, Message, Source | where {($_.Message -like "*Connection request timed out*") -and ($_.Source -like "ASP*")}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not natively in 2003, but with some scripting it can be done.

Natively, you're restricted to the filter categories in the screenshot (right click the Event Log in question, `View -> Filter...`), but with a script you can basically copy out only the events containing certain text to a `.evt` (Event Log) file and open that up.

[image]

Comment: Could I export all event logs to a txt file? Having that, then I could load it to a sql table and filter.

Comment: @user316687 You can.  Right click the log, `Save As...` and you can save it as a tab delimited text file, a `.csv` or a `.evt`.  I might suggest trying to filter by "warning" first, since it seems that those are all warnings.  Could make life easier, depending on what you're trying to do with the logs.

Comment: It's not possible to filter natively in the way I need. Is there any free tool to be recommend?

Comment: @user316687 Not that I know of.  Like I said, I do this with [PowerShell] scripts.  Parse the event log for the events I want, copy them to a new event log, open that.